# Seating $n$ people at $n+k$ seats.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is the problem: We have $n+k$ seats, and we want to seat ***n*** people. What is the probability, that $m$ places $m\le n$ choosen randomly before people sat down will have been all taken after the seating?

My intuition is that to get the probability we will have to divide by binomial coefficient of $n+k$ over n, but I'm not sure how to use the m.

Comment: If you're not sure about how to use $m$, try to set $m=1$ and work that case. After that, try $m=2$. If you do, edit the question with your thoughts about how this could be generalized.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct.
Instead of *seating* people, think of *withdrawing* seated people, then the hypergeometric formula will immediately come to mind, and

Pr = $\dfrac{\binom{m}{m}\binom{n+k-m}{n-m}}{\binom{n+k}{n}}$

Answer (score 0):

if we have $n+k$ seats and $n$ people that means we have $\binom{n+k}{n}$ options to do so, hence $\binom{n+k}{n} = \frac{(n+k)!}{k! n!} $ options.

it's easier to ask: what is the probability that at least one of the $m$ seats will not be taken, which is the complement of the probability that all $m$ seats are taken.